# Angular.js UI Grid place footer above column footer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am replacing a plain HTML table like the one in the snippet below with an Angular.js ui-grid

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td colspan="3">
        table data goes here...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
        Footer heading
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum of col1</td>
      <td>Sum of col2</td>
      <td>Sum of col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
        Footer notes
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see the footer layout is not very simple. I have seen that is possible to customize the `gridFooterTemplate` and the single columns `footerTemplate`. However the grid footer is always placed below the columns footer.

Is it possible to place the grid footer above the columns footer? Alternatively can I create a grid footer template that encloses the columns footer?

Comment: can you explain bit more informal language about your footer section issue I did not get well?

Comment: I'll try... The HTML snippet shows the current table... I want to use a ui-grid to get a similar table with a similar footer section. If I customize the `gridFooterTemplate` I get a similar footer however it is always placed below the row with column total